# /1?seller_id=2 reroutes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My URL is `http://localhost/goconsult/admin/customer-list/1?seller_id=2`

How to re-route this URL in CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$route['admin/customer-list/(:any)'] = 'admin/customer-list/index/$1;
```

Or if url is like

```
http://localhost/goconsult/admin/customer-list/1/?seller_id=2

$route['admin/customer-list/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'admin/customer-list/index/$1/$2;
```

You could just use uri segments instead of query in url

```
http://localhost/goconsult/admin/customer-list/1/2
```

So now the seller id would be

```
$this->uri->segment(4);

echo $this->uri->segment(4);
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment